# C# - Signalr client connection is causing performance issue Windows Service

Tags: c#, performance, windows-services, signalr

Signalr client code is causing performance issue is Windows Service. Windows service is acting as signalr client.

**What we are trying to do:**

Windows service is having one timer, which executes the method(*ConnectToSignalRServer*). If somehow the connection gets closed, there is one event (*Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed*), which will again try to establish the connection by calling the method(*ConnectToSignalRServer*). A while loop is being used in the event (*Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed*) to try reconnecting.

Please find the sample code below and let me know if any issues with the code.

```
    private static HubConnection Connection = null;

    //When the service starts, this method would be called.
    public static bool ConnectToSignalRServer()
    {
        try
        {
            string Url = "http://www.samplesignalrserver.com";
            Connection = new HubConnection(Url);
            var myHub = Connection.CreateHubProxy("SignalHub");
            Connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    Connection.Closed += Connection_Closed;
                }

            }).Wait();


            //Method(RequestData) would be called upon receiveng message from server
            myHub.On<string>("GetMessgeFromServer", type =>
            {
                Task.Run(() => RequestData(type));
            });

            //Method(GetHostName) would be called in server
            myHub.Invoke<string>("GetHostName", BLConstants.strHostName);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //capturing Stacktrace and Message from ex object
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Establish the connection, if the the connection would be closed
    private static void Connection_Closed()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                bool connected = ConnectToSignalRServer();
                if (connected)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //capturing Stacktrace and Message from ex object
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you call "performance issue" ?

Comment: CPU and Memory usage is getting high, we used to see in Task Manager

Comment: How long is the timer to the function `ConnectToSignalRServer` ?

Comment: Timer is 1 minute interval but it would be disabled once the connection gets established.